# JAXB 2 bindings not working properly

Tags: java, jaxb

Consider the following bindings (snippet):

```
<jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='CONDITION']/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='OPERAND'][position()=1]">
    <jaxb:property name="firstOperand"/>
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='CONDITION']/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='OPERAND'][position()=2]">
    <jaxb:property name="secondOperand"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

And the following XML schema (snippet):

```
<xsd:element name="CONDITION">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="OPERAND" type="OPERANDType"/>
                <xsd:element name="OPERATOR" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="OPERAND" type="OPERANDType" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="OPERANDType">
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="SPECIALCONSTANT" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="CONSTANT" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

And the following input:

```
<OPERAND>
<CONSTANT>Test1</CONSTANT>
</OPERAND><OPERATOR>myOperator</OPERATOR>
<OPERAND>
<CONSTANT>Test2</CONSTANT>
</OPERAND>
```

Can somebody explain why "getSecondOperand" returns null, and why "getFirstOperand" actually contains the CONSTANT value of "Test2"?

Using: 
- JAXB 2.2.4u1
- Java 1.6.0_23
- Apache Maven 3.0.1
- maven-jaxb2-plugin version 0.8.0

EDIT: JAXB generates (JavaDoc removed for the accessors/mutators:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="OPERAND" type="{}OPERANDType"/>
 *         &lt;element name="OPERATOR" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="OPERAND" type="{}OPERANDType"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "firstOperand",
    "operator",
    "secondOperand"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "CONDITION")
public class CONDITION {

    @XmlElement(name = "OPERAND", required = true)
    protected OPERANDType firstOperand;
    @XmlElement(name = "OPERATOR", required = true)
    protected String operator;
    @XmlElement(name = "OPERAND", required = true)
    protected OPERANDType secondOperand;

    public OPERANDType getFirstOperand() {
        return firstOperand;
    }

    public void setFirstOperand(OPERANDType value) {
        this.firstOperand = value;
    }

    public String getOPERATOR() {
        return operator;
    }

    public void setOPERATOR(String value) {
        this.operator = value;
    }

    public OPERANDType getSecondOperand() {
        return secondOperand;
    }

    public void setSecondOperand(OPERANDType value) {
        this.secondOperand = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing the bindings doesn't help.  We need to see the generated code.

Comment: @skaffman: Added the generated code. Let me know if anything else can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bindings have caused XJC to generate code that won't work. You've ended up with two Java fields bound to an element called `OPERAND`, bit since there's no implicit, defined order to fields in a Java class (the source-code order means nothing), the data that gets bound to each field is going to be unpredictable.

By default, I assume XJC generated a Java `List` bound to the `CONDITION` element. This is the only configuration that will really work when it comes to binding the incoming XML, due to the lack of expressiveness of Java.

I suggest that you either live with this, and disentangle the operator and operands at runtime with your own code, or you try a non-standard JAXB implementation like [MOXy](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), which has enhanced capabilities for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: What I did is based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868658/xjc-binding-customization-does-not-work-in-jaxb-2-1-3-it-works-in-jaxb-2-0. Avoiding the List<Object> is indeed what I want. So what the person did in the linked question is also broken?

Comment: I just removed the bindings for this part and worked with the list as before, thanks for helping out!